# iOS : Using constraints to make 4s app look good on larger devices?

Tags: ios

I learned a little bit about constraints and added them to one of my scenes on my 4s app. However, it doesn't seem to solve my problem. On the iPhone 4 there isn't enough real estate for everything and on the iPhone 5 there is too much real estate at the bottom. The constraint I was working was is called Top Space to Top Layout Guide. What am I missing? For some reason, I thought it would scale it depending on the size of the device. Is there another technique I can use to solve my problem?

Comment: pls add more information to your question, no one can help you if you just say it doesn't work

Comment: I have a iPhone 4s scene where all controls fill the entire screen and everything looks great. However, on the iPhone 5 there is too much space at the bottom of the screen. I would like the controls to be spaced evenly and proportionatly no matter what kind of device. I have tried using constraints (Top Space to Top Layout Guide). I thought maybe this would scale the controls depending on the device. It doesn't appear to. The scene I am working with is a form. I want the form to look the same no matter what type of device. What constraint technique do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you space your controls your app will simply look stretched up.

Maybe it's useful for you, to define an top layout constraint and move your whole content a bit down or up depending on which device you are running.

You can set up you constraints in Interface Builder and create a normal `IBOutlet`to your constraint.
Now in your `viewDidLoad` you can do stuff like

```
if(self.view.bounds.size.height == 480.0)
{
    self.topLayoutConstraint.constant = 30;
}
```